# ChromeOS Emulator on Windows not available

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, google-chrome-os

I have been trying to create a ChromeOS Emulator using Android Studio running on Windows 11 machine.
While I got some links online to do the same, the URLs mentioned there for ChromeOS repository and system-image doesnt seem to work. Android Studio gives an error saying 'IO exception while downloading manifest'.
Can someone help in creating a ChromeOS emulator on a windows machine using Android Studio ?

Links used(for reference):
Repository - https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome_os_emulator/addon2-1.xml
System Image - https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome_os_emulator/sys-img2-1.xml

Comment: It did not work anymore on macOS either. Because these two XML files are missing now. You can try these two URL with your browser.

Comment: @StoneLam which URLs? you posted nothing, I'd also like to know where to get the system images from

Comment: @RaulG https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome_os_emulator/addon2-1.xml  and https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome_os_emulator/sys-img2-1.xml, Android Studio try to parse the content of these URLs to understand where to download the ChromeOS images. However, they are no longer available now.

Answer (score 1):

You can get Desktop AVD now:

- Install the [canary version of Android Studio (Electric Eel release)⁠](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview)
- Navigate to Tools > AVD Manager
- Click on Create device
- Select Desktop in the category list
- Choose an AVD profile, then click Next
- Select an image, then click Next
- Click Finish

Taken from https://chromeos.dev/en/posts/desktop-avd-in-android-studio#try-out-the-desktop-avd

This is the closest how I get to run the ChromeOS emulator without Chromebook.